# Displaying non-spatial data tables linked to shapefile feature using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, popup

I store a range of data in tables (excel) that I would like to link to a spatial feature in ArcMap so users can access them via this method.  The data tables have a different schemas (may comprise a mix of mechanical, civil and electrical equipment in say 10 different tables), and a mix of equipment would exist in the each site.  The features in the tables haven't been spatially located, and it isn't likely they will be as it isn't critical.

For example, at a water treatment plant we have a range of equipment:

- miscellaneous pumps
- Control panels
- Dosing units
- Tanks
- Cranes
- etc, etc

If there are multiple water treatment plants, I would like the ability to click on spatial polygon representing a particular site and see a list of what assets are located there.  To help with navigating the tables generally I was going to tag them with site they belong to.  If there was only one table I would do this with a join to a polygon with a matching site attribute, but there are multiple tables with differing fields.

Is it possible to display data in a pop-up for example, that has tree structure showing which tables are located at the site, and possibly be able to open each to show what is in each?

I thought about creating different layers for each site with a source query limiting data to the site, but I thought there would be too many layers and I was likely to miss something if it was added at a later date.

Comment: You stated that the tables contain non-spatial data, so a spatial join would be irrelevant, anyhow.  You would need to join by attribute, using a key field.  Eg, a "site" field that is populated with a unique ID for each site.  Then you can join all the tables to the shapefile using the key field.  NB:  It's better to avoid using Excel if possible.  Better copy the data from Excel into a proper database format first.  Excel in ArcGIS can be a bit unreliable, and I wouldn't count on it for joins.  (If you don't have a key field in each table, then you're going to need to generate one.)

Comment: You've tagged QGIS and ArcMap in your question. Please [edit] to select a single software and your question will be reopened.

Comment: I strongly agree with @SonofaBeach with getting your data out of Excel and into a proper database format. The tree like scenario you are asking about is what I would call a [relate](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/essentials-of-relating-tables.htm) but you need to have the site ID assigned to all your assets.